# How can I disable default element in <input type="date" > on mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, firefox

I have an input tag that have an icon for pick date from calendar .
On firefox browser there is an close button after picking date .
How can I disable that button.
[here is that button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrfW6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding required to the input works for me in both Chrome and Firefox:

```html
<input type="time" required>
<input type="date" required>
```

Comment: But what if is not required?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).